# Line break after several results from database

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am pulling out data from a table, but instead of breaking a line after each result(or set of results), I would like to break the line after 'x' amount of those results, so I don't get long pages.

How can this be done with PHP?

Comment: show us your relevant code, then we can work in improve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't posted any code so your question is going to get marked as off-topic.

If you're trying to do line breaks every X number of iterations then just do it.

```
$i = 0;
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1))
{
 if ($i % 5==0) {echo '<div>Multiple of 5, line break here</div>';}
 $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a pagination. Use something like this http://stefangabos.ro/php-libraries/zebra-pagination/